# Bash prompt appearing in middle of the output

Tags: linux, terminal, pipe, fork, ubuntu-16.04

I was working on a problem in fork() and pipe() in C in Ubuntu 16.04 and the output is supposed to be a sorted array of 150 integers. The output is as desired, however, the bash prompt appears in middle of the output. Its posistion is random each time. I have not found any reference of this sort of occurance anywhere. I dont know if it is because of my code or something else. Can you please tell me the reason? This is my code. bubbleSort is the usual bubble sort function.

```
int main(){
int pd1[2], pd2[2], pd3[2], pd4[2], j=0;
int p, ABC[50],D1[50],D2[50], i,D[100], E[150];


if(pipe(pd1)<0){
    printf("Pipe1 creation failed!!...\nExiting...");
    exit(1);
}
if(pipe(pd2)<0){
    printf("Pipe2 creation failed!!...\nExiting...");
    exit(1);
}
if(pipe(pd3)<0){
    printf("Pipe3 creation failed!!...\nExiting...");
    exit(1);
}
if(pipe(pd4)<0){
    printf("Pipe4 creation failed!!...\nExiting...");
    exit(1);
}

p=fork();
if(p<0){
    printf("Fork creation failed!!...\nExiting...");
    exit(1);
}



srand(time(NULL)+p);
for(i=0;i<50;i++){
    ABC[i]=rand()%1000;
}
bubbleSort(ABC,50);
if(!p)
    write(pd1[1],ABC,sizeof(ABC)+1);
else{
    write(pd2[1],ABC,sizeof(ABC)+1);
    if(fork()==0){
        for(i=0;i<50;i++)
            ABC[i]=rand()%1000;
        bubbleSort(ABC,50);
        write(pd3[1],ABC,50);
        if(fork()==0){
            read(pd1[0],D1,sizeof(D1));
            read(pd2[0],D2,sizeof(D2));
            //close(pd1[0]); close(pd1[1]); close(pd2[0]); close(pd2[1]);
            for(i=0;i<50;i++){
                D[i]=D1[i];
                D[i+50]=D2[i];
            }
            bubbleSort(D,100);
            write(pd4[1],D,sizeof(D)+1);
            if(fork()==0){
                read(pd3[0],ABC,sizeof(ABC));
                read(pd4[0],D,sizeof(D));
                //close(pd3[0]); close(pd3[1]); close(pd4[0]); close(pd4[1]);
                for(i=0;i<100;i++)
                    E[i]=D[i];
                for(i=0;i<50;i++)
                    E[i+100]=ABC[i];
                bubbleSort(E,150);
                for(int i=0;i<150;i++)
                    printf("%d %d\n",i,E[i]);       
            }
        }

    }
}
return 0;
```

}

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw6ch.png)

Comment: This is very common behavior.  Your program starts, creates a child, does some stuff, and exits.  Then the shell prints the prompt.  Then the child prints some data.  To prevent this, your process should `wait` for the child before it exits.

Comment: Where are your `pipe` calls?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I have edited the code. Plz do see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is creating child processes, but it is not waiting for them to finish before allowing itself to exit. This means that they keep doing work, even after your initial process has ended, and your shell moves on and prints the prompt.

This can be fixed by calling [`wait(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) from your initial process with the pid of the child processes you create.

Comment: Sorry, i am new with fork() and wait(). What exactly does the arguement &status mean in the wait() and waitpid() functions? It would also help if you could point out what its value would be in this case. Thanks.

Comment: All I could understand was that i had to put a waitpid(q, &status, 1) in the initial process(where q is the pid of the last child), but what goes as its status in the arguement?

Comment: The status argument is a pointer to an integer where the status of the process you're waiting on will be stored. From the man page: "If status is not NULL, wait() and waitpid() store status information in the int to which it points."

Comment: ohh got it. I misunderstood what status was, my bad. Thanks!